# aggregation lookup by unwind is not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup, unwind

Actually, I'm having two schemas named Users and Courses.
I stored all the users id that are mapped to course. Now i want to access all the user data based on user id which is stored in the courses table using aggregate, lookup and unwind. So, please help to fetch all the users data into the courses table.

**I wrote the below in the Courses Controller**

```
   const aggr = Course.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind:"$mapped_to"
        },
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:'users',
                localField:"mapped_to",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as:"result"
            }
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id:"$_id",
                arrayField:{$push:"$mapped_to"},
                result:{$first:"$result"}
            }
        }

       ]).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
       })
```

Here is the Courses Schema of some fields

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Course = new schema({
tag:{
        type:String,
        //required:true,
        minlength:2,
        maxlength:20
    },
   ** mapped_to:{
        type:Array,
        required:true,
    },**
    added_date:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:2,
        maxlength:500
    }
}
```

Here is the Users Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = new schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current aggregation do and how does it differ from what you are looking for?